# bash script for switch stealth mode on macos

Tags: bash, macos

To solve a specific problem i'm trying to make a switch for `stealth mode` on `macos` using bash

Here is part of the code:

```
STEALTH_STATUS=$(/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode)
if [ "$STEALTH_STATUS" = "Stealth mode enabled" ]; then
    /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setstealthmode off
else
    /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setstealthmode on
fi
```

Everything seems to look ok (right?), but it doesn't work. For debug, I changed the reaction to the condition to `True` and `False`:

```
STEALTH_STATUS=$(/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode)
if [ "$STEALTH_STATUS" = "Stealth mode enabled" ]; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

(if we use a `$STEALTH_STATUS` without `"`, we get an error `line 2: [: too many arguments`)

And when executing this code, it always get `False`, which makes it clear that the result of executing the function to set `$STEALTH_STATUS` is not equal to `"Stealth mode enabled"`

But if we run the command in the shell, we can make sure that the mode is enable now

```
$ /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode
> Stealth mode enabled
```

Just another one check to make a sure

```
STEALTH_STATUS=$(/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode)
STRING="Stealth mode enabled"

echo $STEALTH_STATUS
echo $STRING

if [ "$STEALTH_STATUS" = "$STRING" ]; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

And we got...

```
> Stealth mode enabled
> Stealth mode enabled
> False
```

Can someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: You should quote the `$()`.

Comment: what's the output off `printf '%q\n' "$STEALTH_STATUS"`?

Comment: @Fravadona i've got `Stealth\ mode\ enabled\`

Comment: @0stone0 nope, alredy tried

Comment: @Fravadona yes, the problem was in an extra spacebar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from `STEALTH_STATUS=$(/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode)` contains a trailing whitespace, so your `if` check is failing.  You can see it by checking the length of the strings.  One mechanism for trimming the whitespace is to pipe to xargs.

Here is a modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_status="$(/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getstealthmode | xargs)"
enabled="Stealth mode enabled"

echo "${current_status} length: ${#current_status}"
echo "${enabled} length: ${#enabled}"

if [ "$current_status" = "$enabled" ]; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./script 
Stealth mode enabled length: 20
Stealth mode enabled length: 20
True
```

Output without the pipe to xargs:

```
$ ./script 
Stealth mode enabled  length: 21
Stealth mode enabled length: 20
False
```

(Note, you may also want to avoid using all-caps for your variable names per bash scripting best practices)